# Why do I get the error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

This error occurs at the line `m,n = A.shape`:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

I got this message and I don´t know why. It seems that everything is right. Could anyone help me?

```
image = cv2.resize(image, dsize=(224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

A = image.copy()/255

m,n = A.shape  #  HERE IS THE PROBLEM

B = np.zeros((m,n));
i = 2
j = 2
for i in range(m-1):
    for j in range(n-1):
        B[i, j] = (A[i-1, j-1]  +A[i-1, j]  +A[i-1, j+1]
                 + A[i,   j-1]  +A[i,   j]  +A[i,   j+1]
                 + A[i+1, j+1]  +A[i+1, j]  +A[i+1, j+1])
        B[i, j] = B[i, j]/9;
```

Comment: The third value you are getting from `.shape` is the number of image channels. Maybe you could do something like this: `m, n, c = A.shape`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your matrix `A` has three dimensions, not two. This happens, for example, when `image` is a color image. You might want to use the `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` flag to `cv.imread` to ensure that the image is always read as a grayscale image, and therefore will always have only two dimensions.